# How to print this pattern in C++ without using `std::setw`, `std::left` and `std::right`

Tags: c++

I have to write a C++ program to print this pattern:

```
*                  *
* *              * *
* * *          * * *
* * * *      * * * *
* * * * *  * * * * *
```

This is the solution I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        string temp = "";
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            if(j == i)
                temp += "*";
            else
                temp += "* ";
        }
        cout << left << setw(10)<< temp;
        cout << right << setw(10) << temp << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a solution using just simple spaces? Don't just write the five strings in the `cout` statements.

Comment: Maybe you should try yourself.  There are a bunch of questions like this out there that you can reference.

Comment: Use `'*'`, `' '` and counting variables, that simple.

Comment: @honk Simple spaces means space characters(ASCII value 94 in decimal). Yes that's the title of the question.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I did try coding a solution like that, but I am not able to align the stars properly.

Comment: @StupidMan Probably you better post your solution trying that, and point out your what the particular problems are with that one. That's the kind of questions the site actually supports: You show your problems and efforts, we help to fix your problems.

Comment: The deleted answer was actually helpful. I noticed the pattern and it was easy to code. Here's my working solution without the I/O manipulators. http://ideone.com/4r2GWY

Comment: "Simple spaces means space characters", full stop. No need to talk about ASCII. The compiler knows how to encode `'  '` so it works on your system, regardless of whether the system uses ASCII or some other encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily, if you use two string variables, e.g. `left` and `right`, instead of your single `temp` variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string left, right;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if(j - i < 1)
        {
            // Add a star and a space to each side.
            left += "* ";
            right = " *" + right;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add four spaces into the middle between the stars.
            left += "    ";
        }
    }
    cout << left + right << endl;
}
```